# VLC plays full video with stream but only saves audio

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I'm trying to back up a video from a set-top box i got my hands on, it supports streaming over LAN, and I got VLC to play the stream on my computer without using any special setting or else, but when I try to save it, again through vlc, it just makes mp4 with audio. Am I missing some settings or is it something else?

I don't need to use vlc, I just really need to back that one video.